# openni launching errors

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all.

When I tried to launch the openni_camera with the command "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch", I got weird errors.

```
===================================================================================
[openni_node1-1] process has died [pid 8338, exit code -11].
log files: /home/enddl22/.ros/log/d7cb5b9c-42ef-11e0-9bb4-d8d3857b0f6f/openni_node1-1*.log
===================================================================================
```

And roswtf said that

```
===================================================================================
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /openni_node1

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/openni_node1/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/openni_node1/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://BEE-PG-46634:60728]
 * service [/openni_node1/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/openni_node1/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://BEE-PG-46634:60728]

===================================================================================
```

I have diamondback and cturtle ROS packages and properly switched to diamondback using "source ./setup.bash" command.

Any comments could help me a lot.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9224/openni-launching-errors./) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-28**:
Please add the contents of the log file(s) called out: /home/enddl22/.ros/log/d7cb5b9c-42ef-11e0-9bb4-d8d3857b0f6f/openni_node1-1*.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually it seems, this is depending on your PC hardware. I had the same problem, when trying to run openni_camera on a Pentium 4. On several newer computers Core 2 or Core i5 everything runs fine.

In any case, while the OpenNI stuff is compiled using only SSE2, the NITE libs seem to be compiled for newer CPUs (maybe using SSE3 instructions) and will cause "illegal instruction" errors on older machines.

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is the solution to the problems on this thread, but here is how I got openni_camera to compile and work on an older machine that does not have the newer SSE3 requirement that is built into the Diamondback Debian packages and even the CMakeLists.txt file for openni_camera when you download the source.  As you can see from the following thread, the trick is to compile openni_camera with only SSE2 support:

http://answers.ros.org/question/341/how-to-compile-openni_ros-with-sse2-only-support

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1